# USB Type C hub / port replicator

Tags: usb

So I bought a Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro S which has a single usb type c port. I also bought a [usb c hub](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BSJVY7Y) so I could connect it to an external monitor via hdmi.  I also wanted to be able to boot into linux via flash drive, so I bought a [usb c flash drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01AZC3NWY).

Then when I got everything I realized I couldn't plugin the flash drive and the hub at the same time.  The hub appeared to have a usb type c port, but this port appears to only allow me to provide input power and even if it did work as a port I still would need two usb type c ports one for the flash drive and one for power.

I figured I just needed to buy a different usb hub with usb type c ports instead of type a ports... but I can't seem to find a usb type c hub that additional type c ports! They all appear to have female type A ports some with a power pass through and some without but none of them seem to have additional type c ports.

Is there a type C hub that will connect to the Tab Pro S, and will allow me to connect both the external monitor via HDMI and the flash drive at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are USB 3 Type A male to USB Type C female adapters which allows me to plug in my flash disk at the same time.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01ABTHI7C/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01ABTHI7C)

In retrospect maybe I should have gotten a usb c male to usb type a female adapter and just use one of my existing flash drives instead of buying a type c flash disk.

[https://www.amazon.com/USB-Adapter-Converter-Connector-STANDARD/dp/B00ZVRHV2C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZVRHV2C)

Comment: Of course your flash drive will work at the lower USB 3.0 speed (5 Gbit/s), and not at the USB 3.1/C one (10 Gbit/s).